# Nesting 'define' functions in another function in PLAIT, racket

Tags: functional-programming, racket, plai

Is it possible to define function inside another function in plait?
When I do it in Racket it works well but in plait I keep getting errors. Here is an example:

```
(define (fact n)
   (define (it-fact n)
      (if (= n 1)
         n
         (* n (it-fact (- n 1)))))
  (it-fact n))
```

This is a procedure implemented in racket, however if I try to run it in plait I keep getting a "bad syntax" error. Is there any way I could do something similar in plait?

I have searched the plait and racket documentation but to no result.

Comment: "[You can declare local functions and constants by using the `local ` form as a wrapper](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plait/definitions-tutorial.html)"